# Wordpress plugins and git sync across environments

Tags: php, wordpress, git, plugins, synchronization

I've searched a lot about this problem, but I didn't found a "perfect" solution. I am using Wordpress with GIT and I'm currently using this gitignore:

https://gist.github.com/salcode/9940509

My question is on the plugins management:

It's very useful to have plugins tracked across environments and this gitignore tracks them unless you ignore specific plugins (like hello.php ecc..) which is fine. The problem is when the plugins have been updated. The files will sync because they are tracked in the GIT repo, which is ok. But what if the updated version of the plugin needs a DB update/upgrade, too? If so, you must always deactivate and activate again all the updated and pulled plugins to ensure eventual tables of the plugins are synced, too.

Do you have a solution for this problem or it is better to not track the plugins at all and install them manually on each environment which is a little bit frustrating to me?

Thanks

Comment: Your project is an theme, plugin or you are changing the WordPress files? Give some info about this. And if you can, tell why you need to use WordPress with GIT?

Comment: Usually I develop Wordpress themes and sometimes custom plugins. I want to use Wordpress with GIT because I work in a team and we always use GIT as a versioning and sync system across our environments and projects. I've done many Wordpress + GIT websites and I've used different approaches evolving to the best solution. The problem I described is the missing piece to make it work perfectly :).

Comment: But you want to use GIT in the themes or in the WP itself? Doesn't make much sense versioning all the WordPress instalation (for me). It will be updated just like plugins and themes and this can be an problem. Answer this to i give you an answer.

Comment: As I said, I'm using a gitignore file, which ignores the files that are unnecessary to track. If you take a look at the gitignore file I linked you will see what is included in the repo and what not.

Comment: I understand that, but what exactly you want to track with GIT? Thats what i want to know.

Comment: I want to track the custom theme folder and the plugins. It can be derived from the gitignore file I linked.

Comment: Now we are talking. I will give you an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject Plugin dependencies with [TGM Plugin Activation](http://tgmpluginactivation.com/)

This library allow you to make an list of plugins that need to be installed in your theme/plugin. Is very easy to use and give you an better control (force activation/desactivation, private/git plugins, etc).

This way, you don't need to track the plugins folder.

Much better, you can track only your project this way (the plugin or theme only).

NOTE: Even if you use this tool, always integrate with external plugins safely (detect if it is activated, if function exists, using hooks and filters, etc). This way your project cannot crash WordPress.

Comment: Hi, nice suggestion. I'll try it and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. Thank you very much, this library is great for managing plugins. The only thing missing is the following case: I install a plugin, register it in the tgm function commit and push, after some days I decide that this plugin is no longer needed, so I delete it from the tgm function, commit and push. My team will not be able to know that they must delete the plugin as well. Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: You can try to use an WP function to deactivate plugins: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/deactivate_plugins or, you can look at documentation/help on the TGMPA site: http://tgmpluginactivation.com/

Comment: Thanks, I opened an issue on the TGM github here: https://github.com/TGMPA/TGM-Plugin-Activation/issues/722. Anyway this solution solves a lot of my problems so I mark this solution as a correct answer.